# How to initialize db plugin before loading layout.phtml

Tags: zend-framework, layout, load

I want to create menu at run time depending on user privileges that stored in db, I used ACL to grand and revoke resources..

Now I want to load the menu depending on user privileges.

Here's my navigation.phtml sub page

```
<?php

 $resourceLoader = new Application_Plugin_ResourceLoader();
 $namaspace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');

 $db = $registry::get('pmodel_Db');

 $roleId = $namaspace->id;
 $module = $resourceLoader->getUserModulesPrivileges($db, $roleId);

 var_dump($module);

?>
```

I load the database pmodel_Db in bootstrap, I face an exception that

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: registry in D:\wamp\www\zend_apps\inspect\application\layouts\scripts\navigation.phtml on line 6.
```

The problem means that the layout.phtml that include the navigation.phtml page is loaded before the `_initDbRegistry()` method in bootstrap file..

How can I load the pmodel_Db before loading layout ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this

```
 $db = Zend_Registry::get('pmodel_Db');
```

> The problem means that the layout.phtml that include the
>   navigation.phtml page is loaded before the _initDbRegistry() method in
>   bootstrap file

You are wrong here, Zend won't dispatch the request until it bootstrap the resources required.

The way you accessing the registry is wrong.

Comment: I use variable without assigning it to Zend_Registry :S